# Missing date operators in the entry criteria

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, date, entry-criteria

I am creating a Salesfore Data entry source in a Journey. In the second step 'Entry Criteria' I have to apply a filter based on a date field

> 'XXX is greater than 'Today' plus 4 days'

That operator is available in the decision split but not in the entry criteria or filter criteria in the entry source. How is it possible? Is there a way to apply that type of criteria in the entry source?

By the way, I dont see that the date changes when I put the date field equals to 'Today'. It always seems to leave the date when the entry criteria was configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way SF Data entry source works, there has to be a change within SFDC record. So the record has to be updated to not meeting criteria to meeting criteria. You can not say today + 4 since the record will not be updated to kick off the downstream process builder/apex workflow.

I would suggest using a boolean field, that you can set using a process within SFDC that marks it true when the date field is today + 4 and based your filter off this field